# How to import csv file data In Azure blob into a variable in powershell using powershell

Tags: powershell

I have a ask to read a lookup.csv file from azure blob and store the file data into a variable in power shell. So that that variable values  can be used in further code.
Can you help me how to write this code.

```
# Azure Storage Account Config
$StorageAccountName     = "entacc"
$ContainerName          = "raw"

#Get Storage Account context
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey "NNNN" # 
#Get reference for container
$container = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $context
#Get reference for file
# download the test.csv file to the temp folder in runbook
Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container  $container -Blob "Clients_networks.csv" -Context $context
```

Comment: You can use `Get-AzStorageBlobContent` to download your blob, then you can read it as you can with any local file. Not sure why you're still using the AzureAD module tho

Comment: I dont know powershell at all. i am googling and writing the code. But i cant getting to the final output what i expected. Can you help me how to write code using Get-AzStorageBlobContent Please its really urgent for my work.

Comment: note : i should not use any local directory to temporarily hold the csv file data

Comment: What _specific_ issue are you having with `Get-AzStorageBlobContent`